# AWS EKS CoreDNS issue on public subnet

Tags: amazon-eks

I completed the AWS EKS using their setup steps.

AWS EKS ver 1.11, coredns

With the VPC I create two public and two private subnets according to their docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-public-private-vpc.html

Nodes deployed to a private subnet are labeled private and nodes deployed to a public subnet are labeled public.

When I deploy a busybox pod to each nodeSelector (public/private) the public container cannot resolve dns while the private can.

`nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'`

If I ssh onto the public subnet node itself I am able to ping hostnames (ie google.com) successfully.

Any thoughts?

```
# kubectl exec -it busybox-private -- nslookup kubernetes.default

Server:    172.20.0.10
Address 1: 172.20.0.10 ip-172-20-0-10.ec2.internal

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 172.20.0.1 ip-172-20-0-1.ec2.internal
```

```
# kubectl exec -it busybox-public -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    172.20.0.10
Address 1: 172.20.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
command terminated with exit code 1
```

```
# kubectl -n=kube-system get all
NAME                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/aws-node-46626             1/1       Running   0          3h
pod/aws-node-52rqw             1/1       Running   1          3h
pod/aws-node-j7n8l             1/1       Running   0          3h
pod/aws-node-k7kbr             1/1       Running   0          3h
pod/aws-node-tr8x7             1/1       Running   0          3h
pod/coredns-7bcbfc4774-5ssnx   1/1       Running   0          20h
pod/coredns-7bcbfc4774-vxrgs   1/1       Running   0          20h
pod/kube-proxy-2c7gj           1/1       Running   0          3h
pod/kube-proxy-5qr9h           1/1       Running   0          3h
pod/kube-proxy-6r96f           1/1       Running   0          3h
pod/kube-proxy-9tqxt           1/1       Running   0          3h
pod/kube-proxy-bhkzx           1/1       Running   0          3h

NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/kube-dns   ClusterIP   172.20.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   20h

NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/aws-node     5         5         5         5            5           <none>          20h
daemonset.apps/kube-proxy   5         5         5         5            5           <none>          20h

NAME                      DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/coredns   2         2         2            2           20h

NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
replicaset.apps/coredns-7bcbfc4774   2         2         2         20h
```

Going through "Debugging DNS Resolution"
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

Odd that AWS has their coredns pods still labelled kube-dns

```
# kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kubedns
No resources found.

# kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-7bcbfc4774-5ssnx   1/1       Running   0          20h
coredns-7bcbfc4774-vxrgs   1/1       Running   0          20h

# for p in $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name); do kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $p; done
2019/01/31 15:23:36 [INFO] CoreDNS-1.1.3
2019/01/31 15:23:36 [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.10.5, d47c9319
.:53
CoreDNS-1.1.3
linux/amd64, go1.10.5, d47c9319
2019/01/31 15:23:36 [INFO] CoreDNS-1.1.3
2019/01/31 15:23:36 [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.10.5, d47c9319
.:53
CoreDNS-1.1.3
linux/amd64, go1.10.5, d47c9319
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the worker node security groups is where I think I found the issue.

The AWS EKS kube-dns endpoints and pods were on the private subnet.

I have two CloudFormation stacks: one for autoscaling nodes in the private subnets and one for autoscaling nodes in the public subnets.

They didn't have a common security group so the pods running in the public nodes weren't able to access the kube-dns pods running on the private nodes.

Once I update the worker node security groups to allow cross communication the DNS started working.

Please post if anyone sees any unintended consequences.

Comment: Could you please share what you did here:

"Once I update the worker node security groups to allow cross communication the dns started working"

I think I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: With AWS EKS when you create your worker nodes (either via CloudFormation like the tutorial shows or directly via EC2 Auto Scaling) each worker node needs the ability to communicate with the other worker nodes (in addition to the EKS control plane). I had two Auto Scaling groups (one on public subnet other on private subnet) but they didn't have the ability to cross-communicate.  By updating their worker node Security Group I was able to allow "All Traffic" between worker nodes.  Just be sure to specify the other groups security group as the Source. Hope that helps!